# Is it possible to pass a reference of std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm trying to write a function that changes the array outside of it, kind of like passing a value to a function as a reference.
Here's my code:

```
std::array<Card, 52> deck {};
std::array<Card, 52> &deckRef = deck;

initializeDeck(deckRef);
printDeck(deckRef);
```

and

```
void initializeDeck(std::array<Card, 52> deck){
int16_t cardNumber{0};
for(int counterSuit{0}; counterSuit < CardSuit::MAX_SUITS; ++counterSuit)
{
    for(int counterRank{0}; counterRank < CardRank::MAX_RANKS; ++counterRank)
        {
            Card card { static_cast<CardRank::CardRank>(counterRank),
                        static_cast<CardSuit::CardSuit>(counterSuit)};

            deck[cardNumber] = card;
            ++cardNumber;

        }
}}

void printDeck(std::array<Card, 52> deck){
for(int16_t counter{0}; counter < 52; ++counter)
    {
        printCard(deck[counter]);
    }}
```

printDeck prints garbage however if I add a printCard() to initializeDeck(), it prints all the cards just fine, however it doesn't get stored in the original array in main().

I get this error when I do this;

```
void initializeDeck(std::array<Card, 52>& deck)

undefined reference to `initializeDeck(std::array<Card, 52u>)'|
```

Thanks in advance!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try passing a reference to `std::array`? You should have discovered you can.

Comment: You don't pass by a reference.

Comment: You are still passing it by value. The functions need to receive the parameters as a reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass deck as a reference so the outside of the function has the changes. i.e. the code should be

```
void initializeDeck(std::array<Card, 52>& deck){
```

Comment: I've tried that, I get this error when I do so.
undefined reference to `initializeDeck(std::array<Card, 52u>)'|

Comment: Make sure you change both the declaration and the definition to take a reference.

Comment: Yep, I feel dumb now.
Thanks a lot, beginner's mistake I guess!

Comment: @KarimEssam if you don't need the prototype for some other reason, get rid of it and move the function ahead of it's first use in the file. That way you don't have to worry about keeping two pieces in lockstep.

Answer (score 0):

A Slight extension of the topic, but you can generate your deck at compile time if you like: (this example requires c++14, but c++11 can do it with a little more work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

enum class Suit { Spades, Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Suit s) {
    switch (s) {
        case Suit::Spades: return os << "spades";
        case Suit::Diamonds: return os << "diamonds";
        case Suit::Clubs: return os << "clubs";
        case Suit::Hearts: return os << "hearts";
    }
}

enum class Rank { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Rank r) {
    switch (r) {
        case Rank::Two: return os << "two";
        case Rank::Three: return os << "three";
        case Rank::Four: return os << "four";
        case Rank::Five: return os << "five";
        case Rank::Six: return os << "six";
        case Rank::Seven: return os << "seven";
        case Rank::Eight: return os << "eight";
        case Rank::Nine: return os << "nine";
        case Rank::Ten: return os << "ten";
        case Rank::Jack: return os << "jack";
        case Rank::Queen: return os << "queen";
        case Rank::King: return os << "king";
        case Rank::Ace: return os << "ace";
    }
}

struct Card {
    Suit suit;
    Rank rank;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Card& c) {
    return os << c.rank << " of " << c.suit;
}

constexpr Card make_card(size_t index)
{
    return Card {
        static_cast<Suit>(index / 13),
        static_cast<Rank>(index % 13)
    };
}


using Deck = std::array<Card, 52>;

template<size_t...Is>
constexpr Deck generate_deck_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return { make_card(Is)... };
}

constexpr Deck generate_deck()
{
    return generate_deck_impl(std::make_index_sequence<52>());
}


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto deck = generate_deck();
    std::copy(begin(deck), end(deck), ostream_iterator<Card>(cout, ", "));
    cout << endl;

    random_shuffle(begin(deck), end(deck));
    std::copy(begin(deck), end(deck), ostream_iterator<Card>(cout, ", "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is hardly suitable for a beginner!

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet teach them to reach for the stars, Barry. That's what I say. ;-)

Comment: Why `case` then? Wouldn't static array with enumerators as indices work as well and require less code? And `random_shuffle` is deprecaed and going to be removed soon

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot re random_shuffle, you're absolutely right but I felt that the introduction of a `random_engine` initialised by a `random_device` might be distracting so I chose the less correct method for the sake of simplicity. Re lookup tables, well, a switch allows the compiler to do the most efficient thing while a lookup table forces it down one route. Either way, c++ demands that we repeat ourselves, which is a shame, so both methods require equal care. There really should have been a 'named enum' in c++11 IMHO.